# Configure a local server for LAN play without access to the router?

Tags: hosting, server-administration, networking

My classmates and I from university want to create a server just for ourselves (Counter Strike for example, but no preference).

The thing is because we are at university we don't have access to the router and do port-forwarding. Is there away around this?

Comment: Any game with Lan probably doesn't need port forwarding

Comment: Ask your IT to let it through?  You won't need port forwarding, but you'll need your university's IT to allow it.

Comment: @Frank "Dear IT, we'd love to install some crap you spend good part of your time removing, so we can waste our time, and our teachers' time to play some games. We swear its games and not viruses, that you will have to remove, also while we are at it, can we get some two-way communication between our PCs so we can play the games properly. Thanks!" .....

Comment: @ИвоНедев hahaha yeah that was a good one, thnx  for the effort guys.

Answer (score 2):

Rent a (online) server, as you'll likely not be allowed to host any kind of server within your university network anyway.

Also you'll get something that's easier to setup than what you're trying to do right now.

Comment: Thnx very much, I'll have that on mind because honestly its too much of stuff to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly depends on what you wana play ... If its CS:GO you only needvalid steam accounts and valid copies of the game, be friends on steam and go MM with freinds. If its 1.6 (or source) you can get it working the usual way (Find Server -> Lan) if it doesn't work you might get it to work with "connect public.ip.of.host" In the console. We used to do the same shit, never even tried to access the routers... My point is from all the MP games I used to played, only minecraft required tinkering with the router, ever ....

Comment: So you propose by LAN, so my guess is wifi Ad-hoc?

Comment: Well unless your school's IT department is either incredibly stupid or incredibly advanced, in any chance the PCs are already connected locally (LAN) So just go in game, start a game, and try to join from other PCs